# Update records using lwc

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, update, updaterecord

I have created an lwc component to enter the date picklist and text values and when I click save it gets recorded in the opportunity objects related fields.Right now I have created another object named Site which I have given a lookup relationship to the opportunity object.Is it possible that in any way I enter the data in the component I placed in the opportunity object and it gets entered in the site objects related fields through lwc.

NB:I know it is possible using an apex class.I am planning to do without an apex class.

Comment: You mention "I am planning to do without an apex class.", are you looking to complete all this from the client-side? If not and willing to go server-side but using declarative, how about a Record-Triggered Flow on the Opportunity object?

Comment: If you do not want to use Apex, you can try Salesforce User Interface API to update records.

Answer (score 0):

Use Salesforce UI Record API methods if you don't want to use apex classes .

Have a look at this link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record

In this way you can update Records without the use of Apex Classes

Comment: @Ajay Karthik Thanks